# Scrollbar Size in ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, scrollviewer

How can I programatically determine the width or height of a Scrollbar in the ScrollViewer?  Not the current size based on the current state of the ScrollViewer (since I can simply test the visibility of the scrollbar and calculate against the ViewerPortWidth/Height and the ScrollViewer ActualWidth/Height).

I need to know what size the Scrollbar's *could* be based on the templated width.  The default is 18 (with a margin of -1).  But we all know what could happen if I use the magic number of 18 in my calculations.  Some of my users could template the Scrollbars in the ScrollViewer then I'd be screwed.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't understand the problem - why can't you use e.g. (ActualWidth - ViewPortWidth) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine the width of the vertical scroll bar in a ScrollViewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777384/determine-the-width-of-the-vertical-scroll-bar-in-a-scrollviewer)

Comment: It's not duplicate, there's no such SystemParameters properties in Silverlight

Answer (score 2):

You can use SystemParameters.ScrollWidth.

Comment: There is no ScrollWidth property on SystemParameters in silverlight

Answer (score 1):

You can use Silverlight Toolkit's VisualTreeHelper in the following way:

```
var verticalScrollbar = view.GetVisualChildren().OfType<FrameworkElement>()
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "VerticalScrollBar");
var horizontalScrollbar = view.GetVisualChildren().OfType<FrameworkElement>()
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "HorizontalScrollBar");
var width = verticalScrollbar == null ? 0 : verticalScrollbar.ActualWidth;
var height = horizontalScrollbar == null ? 0 : horizontalScrollbar.ActualHeight;
```

where **view** is an instance of ScrollViewer (I guess you've got the instance).