# How to find Vertical Scrollbar width of a Scrollviewer in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer and in that I am showing the Vertical Scrollbar, Now on changing resolution of the system I want to get the width of the scrollbar. I went through [One StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777384/determine-the-width-of-the-vertical-scroll-bar-in-a-scrollviewer) there they mention to check for SystemParameters.ScrollWidth Property but again I din find any help from their. Can anybody please help me to fix my issue. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Check for this code, This will give you the default Scrollbar width:
double scrollBarwidth=SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

By the way why you are looking for it, any how the default vale of the VerticalScrollBarWidth is 17 I think.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Yeah I checked, it is giving me 17 pixel but I was thinking whether its changing according to DPI settings so that's why I was looking for it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think [`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarwidth.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you need to express it in XAML, you can do it like this:     <ColumnDefinition Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}" />

Comment: I got a cast exception because the value is a double, but ColumnDefinition is a GridLength. The solution I used:  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}}"/>

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if this is the correct answer. Every WPF control can be restyled so even the scrollbar. So *SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth* works only if it is used as default scrollbar. The correct solution would be to find the vertical scrollbar in the visual tree and measure it's ActualWidth. It is the most precise measurement.

Comment: How would you go about doing that in XAML?

Comment: @Grubsnik maybe by binding to a property that you'll create ... nothing straight forwards pops to mind

Comment: @Grubsnik If youcan provide the XAML I can try to write it. It is a custom solution so it is hard to give you and immediate answer.

Comment: @Patrik thanks for the offer, but the XAML code and project is long gone from my mind at this point. Can't even remember the exact problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Exactly this.... I wanted to offset another uielement by the scrollbar width if the visibility changed. To do this I created a couple converters, one that converts a double to thickness with a mask (top,right etc) and a second that derives from this, taking a scrollviewer and passing in the scrollbar width.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by some answers, `SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth` returns the constant that is used for system controls.
However, this value is not reliable. For example, the `ScrollBar` elements could have been customized or have their visibility set to `Visibility.Collapsed` (so that they are no longer a child of the visual tree and therefore not impacting the rendered layout anymore).

To get the current width you must locate the scroll bars in the visual tree of the `ScrollViewer`.
The `ScrollViewer` defines the `ScrollBar` elements as template parts named `"PART_VerticalScrollBar"` and `"PART_HorizontalScrollBar"`.

You can use the following extension method (extending `DependencyObject`) to get the vertical `ScrollBar`:
**Usage**
For example, to get the `ScrollBar` width of the vertical `ScrollViewer` of the `DataGrid` control use

```cs
if (dataGrid.TryFindVisualChildElementByName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", out ScrollBar scrollbar))
{
  double verticalScrolBarWidth = scrollbar.Width;
}
```

```cs
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
  public static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(
    this DependencyObject parent, 
    string childElementName, 
    out TChild resultElement) where TChild : FrameworkElement
  {
    resultElement = null;
    if (parent is Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      if (child is FrameworkElement frameworkElement 
        && frameworkElement.Name.Equals(childElementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        resultElement = frameworkElement as TChild;
        return true;
      }

      if (child.TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(childElementName, out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```