# Find width of a scrollbar

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal, scrollviewer

Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701760/how-to-find-vertical-scrollbar-width-of-a-scrollviewer-in-c-sharp), but for UWP. In particular, I can't find any SystemParameters class, so the answer there does not work in my case.

Also important: If at all possible, I would like to be able to get the width a scrollbar would have if it existed. In other words, there are cases where the scrollbar does not exist yet, but user input is likely to cause it to be created. In such a case, I want to be able to know what width it is expected to have if/when it is created. (I realize something unexpected might cause the answer to be wrong; that's ok, as long as I'm getting the usual expected answer.)

Comment: Hmm. In `System.Windows.Forms` it's `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`. Not sure if that's the same in UWP though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Neme's answer said, you can use [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to retrieve the [ScrollBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.scrollbar.aspx) and then use [ActualWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) property to get its width.

However, if you didn't change `VerticalScrollBar`'s styles and templates, the width of `VerticalScrollBar` would always be **12**. You can find this in [ScrollBar styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx).

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="12" />
    ...
</Style
```

For `VerticalScrollBar`, its width won't change so its `ActualWidth` would always be 12. And for `HorizontalScrollBar`, its height won't change so its `ActualHeight` would always be 12. These value changes only when we change scrollbar's style or template. And in this scenario, we should know the width we've set, or we can retrieve it at runtime by using [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx).

Comment: I found that too, hardcoded in the templates. It seems to me like there should be a resource for it to easily get the default value (in case it ever changes).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no better way other than digging in the properties yourself. There really is a lot of hacking you have to do in UWP. For example, it looks like there is no way to get the ScrollBar from a ScrollViewer directly (you  also can't do `FindName` on the template or even derive from it to use `GetTemplateChild`), but these lines should work around that:

```
var rootElement = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollViewer, 0);
var scrollBar = (ScrollBar)rootElement.FindName("VerticalScrollBar");
```

You could access the `ActualWidth` property of the ScrollBar, but that will be zero if it's not visible. Luckily, I found out that `MinWidth` contains the right value.

You do have to have a visible ScrollViewer.